# small project idea to clear synchronization concept

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I need idea for small project which will clear my synchronization concepts clear.
Basically any multi-threading application. 
I know the idea and theory, but not able to figure out how to go more deep in details.

I am planning to use `C++` and `pthreads`

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43994/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://spinroot.com/spin/Doc/course/2005_downey_semaphores.pdf).

There are many problems that you can try to solve. After each problem there is a hint that should help you and at the end there is a solution that you can compare with yours.

Hope this helps.